# Y axes has unexpected value when drawing rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am drawing a rectangle using the drawRect method. I use x, y to give initial values for the rectangle. And these values are x = 150, y=300. 
So I've got this:

[image]

Now I made the printing of coordinates in the log when touching the screen.

The problem is when I am touching the up left corner of rect (150, 300) I'm getting next values in the log:

D/TOUCH:: x=153, y=370

It is the correct value for X but incorrect for Y because as said I put initial Y==300. My question is why it is so?

Comment: are you using `MotionEvent#getRawX/Y`?

Comment: No. I'm just using getX, getY methods

Comment: what you see if you tap on the top/left corner of your custom view?

Comment: I see 
D/TOUCH:: x=0, y=72
and this is bad

Comment: how are you getting `MotionEvent`s? from your custom view's `View#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method? or maybe from `Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` or similar?

Comment: From onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) inside my 
main activity

Comment: wrong, use it from your view

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, your welcome - now if you use `getY` you will get the right y value of your view and if you use `getRawY` you will get the y value of the whole screen (in your case +72 pixels)

Comment: Yeah. But now another problem. When I move onTouchEvent method to my View class  ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP events stoped working..

Comment: return `true` from `View#onTouchEvent` method

Comment: конечно, пожалуйста ;-)

Comment: ха-ха! Так надо было с этого и начинать:)

Comment: no, it was google translator only, but it seems it works, and, yes, i am aware you are kazakh not russian...  ;-)